# LINQ Take(); how to handle when null or fewer records than requested available?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, take

I want to filter my results to take only the X amount of records. I am wondering how does `Take()` work?

On this site I found: http://www.hookedonlinq.com/TakeOperator.ashx

It says `Take()` "Throws an ArgumentNullException if source is null." So what should I do? I can't guarantee that everytime I do a `Take()` I will have some records in that table or not.

So do I first have to do a count? Then do another query to make sure there is some records to grab?

Also what happens if the I have a `Take(2)` but only 1 record will it throw this same exception?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There's a difference between a null reference and an empty collection. It's fine to call Take on an empty collection. And the argument specifies a maximum number to take, so it's also fine to specify more than there are items in the collection.

I recommend referring to MSDN for precise details like this.

For Linq to Objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx

For Link to databases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx

Comment: Is there away to make it take all results or limit the number of results? Like only depending on certain conditions I want to limit the number of results or will I have to split this apart(ie to different methods)?

Comment: @chobo2: That's exactly what it does already. If you ask for 5 items but it only has 3, it will give you all 3.

Answer (score 14):

That null reference exception is only if you are doing that against an object source such as:

```
List<MyObject> myList = null;
myList.Take(5); // this would produce the error, of course
```

When you are doing Linq to SQL it'll return an EMPTY enumerator of your data, not a null reference.  On the same token, if you are attempting to take more than is available it'll only take up the amount available.  I use this method to page data in some instances and definitely a lot of the time when I'll ask for more records than the list has available.

Comment: Calling any method on `null` is going to throw a NullReferenceException. ArgumentNullException will be thrown if you invoke Take as a static method: `List<object> list = null; Enumerable.Take(list, 5);`

Answer (score 2):

Take will through an exception if the object invoking it is null.  Chances are you will not have a null object, and having no or less rows is not the same (I am sure you understand the semantics).

If you are using a Linq to SQL context and querying in the fashion of

```
Context.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID > 0).Take(2);
```

in the case of the `Where` returning zero results, you will not get a null exception, because your query has not yet been executed, then in the case of it only containing 1 result, you will end up only getting 1 result back.  `Take` limits the amount of records returns.

Comment: "in the case of the Where returning zero results, you will not get a null exception, because your query has not yet been executed" - No. You will not get a null exception because if `Where` returns no results, it returns a non-null reference to an object representing an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of items before you Take():

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
            int count = a.Count > 12 ? 12 : a.Count;
            a.Take(count);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx): "`Take<TSource>` enumerates `source` and yields elements until `count` elements have been yielded or `source` contains no more elements. If `count` exceeds the number of elements in `source`, all elements of `source` are returned."