# How might I take two random records from a list using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

How might I take two random records from a list using Linq?

Comment: check this post...
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364033/linq-take-question

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(n => lst[rnd.Next(0, lst.Count)]).ToList();
```

Comment: nice, I wouldn't use it.. but real cute... +1

Answer (score 3):

For `Linq-to-Objects` and `EF4` it's pretty simple

```
db.Users.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2)
```

---

For `Linq-to-SQL` You can check this article
http://michaelmerrell.com/2010/03/randomize-result-orders-in-t-sql-and-linq-to-sql/

Add function Random mapped to SQL function `NEWID` to DataContext.

```
partial class DataContext
{
    [Function(Name = "NEWID", IsComposable = true)]
    public Guid Random()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var qry = from row in DataBase.Customers
          where row.IsActive
          select row;

int count = qry.Count();
int index = new Random().Next(count);

Customer cust = qry.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/31/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-four.aspx

Comment: And what? How does it collide?

Comment: Depending on the sort algorithm used, that may result in an infinite loop.( A>B at time t1 and A<B at time t2), Additionally why to sort just to take two random element?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way. You can try this, not pretty though.

```
int randomRecord = new Random().Next() % List.Count(); //To make sure its valid index in list
var qData = List.Skip(randomRecord).Take(1); 
var qValue = qData.ToList().First();
```

Comment: wont this overflow at the end? shouldn't it be % List.Count()-1 ?

Comment: Don't think so... `m % p` will produce values from `0` to `p-1`.

Comment: I think, % will always give max remainder of List.Count() - 1, which would be the last element.

Comment: You're taking only one and you should take two, and this increase the odds of the last item in the list. **Your answer isn't random enough.**

Comment: I think the above logic can be enhanced to take 2 random elements easily using the ? operator. Again I am not saying I have the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me, it ensures no duplicates are returned:

```
public List<T> GetRandomItems(List<T> items, int count = 3)
{
    var length = items.Count();
    var list = new List<T>();
    var rnd = new Random();
    var seed = 0;

    while (list.Count() < count)
    {
        seed = rnd.Next(0, length);
        if(!list.Contains(items[seed]))
            list.Add(items[seed]);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use Linq to get two random records?

Create a Random instance and get two random number whose values are less than the length of the list.

List has Indexer property, so doing List[index] is not costly.

Keep it **simple**. Always prefer readability. If you just make things complicated, the programmers who are going to maintain your code will have hard time.

I am just curious to know why exactly you want to do this in **Linq**? That just seems like a overhead to me.

am I missing something?

Comment: because i want display 2 records on my page which will change after every postback. so i need 2 get 2 random records from list